# Fitting a range of distribution and test for goodness of fit - choose based on p-value or chi-squared values?

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, p-value, nonparametric, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have data for which I want to study the best distribution that fits this data. I am following this [blog post](https://pythonhealthcare.org/2018/05/03/81-distribution-fitting-to-data/) to do my experiments. Basically the following things are happening:

1. fit a number of distributions to my data
2. compare goodness of fit with a chi-squared value
3. test for significant difference between observed and fitted distribution with a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Lets say we have a list of 10 distributions we are interested in. For each of these, I record the chi squared value as well as the p-value from the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. Lets say I record them in a data frame.

Now what I want to do is I want to sort my dataframe by the chi squared values. The smaller the chi squared the better. However, the distribution with the smallest chi squared value is not the one with the highest p-value. If I sort this data frame rather by descending order of the p-vallue, I get different results.

The question is, how do I decide the best fit ? Based on chi squared values or p-values ? And is it normal that the distribution with the smallest chi squared is not the one with the highest p-value ?

**EDIT**

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50819970/11212687) that recommends using statistic values rather than p-values in tests like Anderson Darling and Kolmogorov-Smirnov because these measures reflect relative distances between actual and hypothetical, but I do not understand clearly why p-values are not the best reference. Can someone elaborate ?